# Angular curly braces not working, basic code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js">              
    </script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 20px 20pc;">
    <div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-repeat="item in 'somewords'.split('')">
            {{$index + 1}}. {{item}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone, I've tried to look up for some old post already but found nothing that could really help me.
I'm learning Angular and in a Tutorial they use this code that is supposed to count and split the letters in the word given.
The problem I'm having is that I get the curly braces as if they where some text in HTML. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got any console errors?

Comment: Do you have a js file? You still need to initiate the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with the duplicates. You should use `track by` to solve the issue.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in 'somewords'.split('') track by $index">
        {{$index + 1}}. {{item}}
</div>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/razvan-tudosa/pen/NRjGqE?editors=1010) is a codepen. Also [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) is some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I see a `ng-app="app"`, but I don't see any code that initializes a module (with the name 'app'). Because you don't use any data that is initialized in any code, you can just rewrite it as `<div ng-app>`.

The other possibility is to define the module (which you'll probably need anyway if you dive deeper in the tutorials):

```
angular.module("app", []);
```

**EDIT**

As @Peter_Fretter correctly mentioned, it will still not work, because you have duplicates in the `ng-repeat`. You can fix that with using the `track by $index`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in 'somewords'.split('') track by $index">
    {{$index + 1}}. {{item}}
</div>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3aj2f3f/)

Comment: It's possible he didn't post the JS file. Even with that declaration of the module, the code would not work. Check out my answer for the problem.